# Sort of li's which contain ol's or ul's fails with HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy

Tags: jquery, sorting, append, appendchild

I am creating rich text with CKEditor and embedding the resulting html into div's contained within li's within an unordered list (ul).  I sort the li's using jQuery and various comparisons.  When the rich text itself contains ul's or ol's, which CKEditor will allow, the sort fails with the message in FF Firebug:

"HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy on line"

and cites this code from jQuery:

```
append: function() {
    return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 ) {
            this.appendChild( elem );
        }
    });
},
```

When the html does not contain any ul's or ol's, the sort works fine.

Here is the HTML context:

An unordered list where each li is classed "RetailerSearchSectionLine" and contains div's containing the rich text as html.

Here is one of the jQuery sort functions which fails:

```
var TransferArray = $(".RetailerSearchSectionLine").toArray().sort(function(a, b)
{
    var distance1 = $(a).data("DistanceFromReferenceLocation");
    var distance2 = $(b).data("DistanceFromReferenceLocation");
    return (distance1 - distance2);
});
$("#RetailerSearchSectionBody ul").append(TransferArray);
```

Any suggestions?  I am thinking of sorting keys to the array and then rearranging the ul based on the sorted result.  But that is a lot of work which actually may not work if there is some basic issue I am not seeing with lists within lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
$("#RetailerSearchSectionBody ul").append(TransferArray);
```

doesn't look right because `$("#RetailerSearchSectionBody ul")` may select a collection (including child ULs) rather than a unique element.

The following should safely select a unique element :

```
$("#RetailerSearchSectionBody").children("ul").eq(0).append(TransferArray);
```

If that doesn't work, then it's arguably more normal to perform the sort on the original jQuery-wrapped elements rather than breaking out into a genuine array, as follows :

```
Array.prototype.sort.call($(".RetailerSearchSectionLine"), function(a, b) {
    var distance1 = $(a).data("DistanceFromReferenceLocation");
    var distance2 = $(b).data("DistanceFromReferenceLocation");
    return (distance1 - distance2);
}).each(function(i, item) {
    $("#RetailerSearchSectionBody").children("ul").eq(0).append(item);
});
```

It's probably academic which approach you adopt because the sort itself appears not to be the problem. Anyway, this is something else you could try.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you.  The first of your two suggestions worked perfectly.  I guess it must have been selecting the embedded ul's and thereby throwing array transfer out of kilter.  I will look into your second suggestion so that I understand it completely.

Comment: I suppose I could also id the ul and refer to it directly (there is only one).  I will also give that a try.  Thanks again.